# How to combine two sentences into one sentence with relative clauses?

Tags: american-english

How to combine two sentences into one sentence with relative clauses?
Also is this written naturally?

1. The man is carrying a bag.
2. It's very heavy.

1+2= the man is carrying a bag that very heavy.

Comment: Your solution does not work as written. You're missing an *is*: "The man is carrying a bag that *is* very heavy". Without the second *is*, the sentence is broken and ungrammatical. Alternatively, you can say "*The man is carrying a very heavy bag*".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can combine these sentences  with a non-defining relative clause as follows:

"The man is carrying a bag, which is very heavy".

Comment: No you can't. You have to follow the rule. But thanks show me else option. It might be help me. But please let me know once more.

Comment: User1917227, it's according to the rule. Another example: She is studying to become a doctor, which is difficult. I don't know what is confusing you.